# Filling missing NAs not working

Tags: pandas

I am having an issue with `SettingWithCopyWarning` and values not being replaced. I searched on this site pretty extensively, and all I'm seeing in terms of dealing with `SettingWithCopyWarning` is to use `copy()`. However, trying to replace any missing values in col1 with the values in col2 even with the following code is not working for me-

```
import numpy as  np
import pandas as pd
import copy
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,np.nan,3], 'b':[5,6,7]})
test2 = test.copy()
test3 = test.copy()
test2.loc[np.isnan(test2['a']) & (np.isnan(test2['b']) == False)]['a'] = 
    test3.loc[np.isnan(test3['a']) & (np.isnan(test3['b']) == False)]['b']

print(test2)
```

The `NaN` in the first column is still there, and I am still getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,np.nan,3], 'b':[5,6,7]})

test['a'] = test['a'].fillna(test['b'])
#alternative
#test['a'] = test['a'].combine_first(test['b'])
print (test)
     a  b
0  1.0  5
1  6.0  6
2  3.0  7
```

EDIT:

Solution with `loc` is really similar, only remove `][` for avoid [chaining indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/2901002):

```
test2.loc[np.isnan(test2['a']) & (np.isnan(test2['b']) == False), 'a'] = \
    test3.loc[np.isnan(test3['a']) & (np.isnan(test3['b']) == False), 'b']
print (test2)
     a  b
0  1.0  5
1  6.0  6
2  3.0  7
```

Comment: That seems like a nice workaround (which works fine), but what did I miss in terms of using loc?